# Are the AOSP Email and Calendar apps dead?

Tags: cyanogenmod, calendar, stock-email-app, vanilla-android

Are the AOSP Email (com.android.email) and Calendar (com.android.calendar) apps dead?  I cannot find any information on their development, though they appear to have been stuck on version 6.0.1 for some time.  They are still distributed as part of CyanogenMod.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak to cyanogen mod, however my understanding is that cyanogen mod has been taken over/morphed into what is now known as the  Lineage OS Distribution here: https://lineageos.org/ perhaps you can get more info there or check on the android open source project here [AOSP Platform Email](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email/) and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/).

Regarding how to install them, see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229303/install-specific-versions-of-aosp-calendar).