# Install specific versions of AOSP Calendar

Tags: applications, installation, apk, calendar, aosp

I would like to use an older version of [AOSP Calendar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/). Namely a good version before the 2019 update that is described [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/aosp-application-updates.html) as follows:

> New events cannot be created and existing events cannot be edited or deleted.

There are many branches and tags [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/), but some of their titles are not clear, and I don't see APK files there. How exactly can I install specific versions?

Comment: Of course you don't see any APK files there, this is the AOSP source code repository. If you want an APK from it you have to compile it yourself. Unfortunately the app is not a standard Android Studio project but is designed to be compiled as part of AOSP. I am not sure if there is a way to manually start compiling via `Android.mk`. Most likely you have to download and build a complete AOSP image to build the AOSP calendar.

Comment: @Robert Where exactly could I ask for a built version for download? Otherwise the installation of this app is much more difficult than of apps that are in app stores.

Comment: You can try to download older LineageOS ROM images and try to extract the contained calendar APK file. For extracting the image you may use https://github.com/cyxx/extract_android_ota_payload (untested). But I am not sure if the AOSP calendar app works if installed as regular (non-system) app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AOSP Calendar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/) is in a repository tool (Google Git) that use Google with a lot of project.

### Compile it by yourself

You could download it:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar
```

and you  could select the branch/tag that you want.

```
git fetch origin nameBranch/nameTag && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD && git checkout nameBranch/nameTag
```

Of this way, you obtain the code of the Calendar AOSP but as you said, in this repository is not the package of the application, so, you should compile it. As it is part of the Android system is neccesary to compile it with the rest of AOSP, because, [it has some dependences](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/refs/heads/master/Android.mk).

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    android-common \
    libchips \
    colorpicker \
    android-opt-timezonepicker \
    androidx.legacy_legacy-support-v4 \
    calendar-common
```

Once you had it compiled, you don't have problems to install it, because althought it is a part of AOSP it is not a system application.

***But, this is not a quickly way to obatin the APK file.***

### Obtain it of system.img

First, you need to obtain a AOSP or Lineage ROM system image before the 2019 (because, the commit that you don't want is in 2019). For this way, you need to use [this tool](https://github.com/anestisb/android-simg2img). Once downloaded and installed:

```
mkdir system_lineage
simg2img system_lineage.img system_lineage.raw
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system_lineage.raw system_lineage
cd system_lineage
```

And you need to found it in this system directory (I think that it was in *system/app/Calendar* or something similar)

### Try to obtain it in some mirror

It is possible that some mirror have this apk in the server. You could try to obtain it in [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/lineageos/) for example.

Comment: Thanks, I found a good version [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/lineageos/calendar-2/) as you suggested! For the other options: What is the command to compile it? I don't understand the names of branches/tags, are they explained somewhere, which ones would you recommend? Where do I get `system_lineage.img`? Maybe I can directly get `system_lineage.raw` somewhere?